# Access mobile router externally. Public/Private IPs?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, dynamic-dns

Ive got a mobile router running of a mobile SIM which I would like to access externally through DDNS. The public IP is 49.x.x.x however within the router (Comset CM685 Mobile Router) it says that the WAN IP is 100.x.x.x. I believe this may be because of the the Carrier-Grade NAT.

Firstly, should the WAN IP ideally be the same as the Public IP?

Secondly, Is there any way i can access this router remotely? If i try to ping any of the IPs it simply times out. DDNS points to the public IP but it seems to lead nowhere.

Any advice would be highly recommended. Thank you all.

Comment: From the router datasheet it looks like it has a designated WAN RJ45 port, so the WAN IP would refer to the address on that port in no relation to the cellular connection. You'd need to contact your carrier to learn how they translate the addresses and if they allow inbound traffic at all.

Comment: May I suggest you read Wikipedia on `NAT, Public IP, and Private IP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you only have to rent public IP to connect to you router from outside.

There is no way to connect if you WAN IP is not public.

In theory, you would be able to do it if your provider allows passing packets via the border router to your router within provider's internal LAN, but no provider permits this for security reasons. All packets addressed to internal LAN from the Internet are blocked by default.